# Read a complex, and long text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, text-files

I have a very long text file which contains the data from 4 different stations with different time steps:

```
1:00
station 1
a number 1  (e.g.0.6E-06)
matrix1 (41x36)
station 2
number 2    (e.g.0.1E-06)
matrix2 (41x36)
station 3
number 3   (e.g.0.2E-06)
matrix3 (41x36)
station 4
number 4    (e.g.0.4E-06)
matrix4 (41x36)

2:00
station 1
a number   (e.g.0.24E-06)
matrix5 (41x36)
station 2
a number     (e.g.0.3E-06)
matrix6 (41x36)
station 3
number     (e.g.0.12E-06)
matrix7 (41x36)
station 4
number     (e.g.0.14E-06)
matrix8 (41x36)
```

.....
and so on

I need to read this data by each station and each step, and noted that each matrix should be scaled by multiplying with a number above it. An example is here: https://files.fm/u/sn447ttc#/view/example.txt

Could you please help?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea here would be to read the textfile using `fopen` and `textscan`. Afterwards you can search for appearances of the Keyword `FACTOR` to subdivide the output. Here's the code:

```
fid=fopen('example.txt'); % open the document
dataRaw=textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter',''); % read the file with no delimiter to achieve a cell array with 1 cell per line of the text file
fclose(fid); % close the document
rows=cellfun(@(x) strfind(x,'FACTOR'),dataRaw,'uni',0); % search for appearances of 'FACTOR'
hasFactor=find(~cellfun(@isempty,rows{1})); % get rownumbers of the lines that contain the word FACTOR
dataRaw=dataRaw{1}; % convert array for easier indexing
for ii=1:(numel(hasFactor)-1) % loop over appearances of the word FACTOR
    array=cellfun(@str2num,dataRaw(hasFactor(ii)+2:hasFactor(ii+1)-1),'uni',0); % extract numerical data
    output{ii}=str2num(dataRaw{hasFactor(ii)+1})*cat(1,array{:}); % create output scaled by the factor
end
array=cellfun(@str2num,dataRaw(hasFactor(end)+2:end),'uni',0);
output{end+1}=str2num(dataRaw{hasFactor(end)+1})*cat(1,array{:}); % These last 2 lines add the last array to the ouput
outputMat=cat(3,output{:}); % convert to a 3-dimensional matrix
outputStations=[{output(1:4:end)} {output(2:4:end)} {output(3:4:end)} {output(4:4:end)}]; % Sort the output to have 1 cell for each station
outputColumnSums=cellfun(@(x) cellfun(@sum,x,'uni',0),outputStations,'uni',0); % To sum up all the columns of each matrix
outputRowSums=cellfun(@(x) cellfun(@(y) sum(y,2),x,'uni',0),outputStations,'uni',0);
```

This approach is pretty slow and probably can be vectorized, but if you don't need it to be fast it should do the job. I created a cell-output with 1 cell per array and a 3 dimensional array as optional output. Hope that's fine with you

Comment: Thanks Max, but there is an error with your code: Undefined variable "rowInds" or class "rowInds".

Comment: Thanks for your patient and helping me.  How about if I want to separate the data by each station, so it looks easier.

Comment: I has been noticed that: Cannot display summaries of variables with more than 524288 elements

Comment: What do you mean? You want a single variable for each station? That would be over 1.000 variables are you sure, you want that? You can just achieve that by dynamic variable naming which is very bad programming practice. But did you check the cell-array version? In the Output-variable there is one cell for each station and you can easily display it.

Comment: Dear Max, I just mean that I wish to get the data station by station separating into each matrix (variable), but each matrix (or variable) should cover all time steps.

Comment: I don't really get your intention, sorry. And what are your time steps? The variable 'output' in my code contains each 41x36-matrix in a single cell. Try for example typing output{1} in the command-line. That will give you your first station. output{2} gives you the 2nd station and so on....

Comment: Dear Max, your code works for me, but the fact is that it gives me 1x1523 cells which contain the data from 4 stations over all time-steps. Ideally I want to get the data for each station over all time steps. It means that the each cell contains 1523/4 ~ 380 cells, so I can analyse the data separately. My apologies for taking for time and I appreciate your help.

Comment: alright, I think I got, what you want now. Check the code that I added to my answer and let me know if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Dear Max, I think you have done a great job for me. May I ask you one more thing: how could I sum  all comlumns (from 1 to 36) in each matrix and return to another output? Great thanks

Comment: I added another line of code, to do that ;) If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick.

Comment: Great Max. How about sum of all rows in each matrix and return to another output? How could I do that? Hope this is my last enquiry :) Thanks

Comment: I added one more line, which is pretty much the same as the column sum, check it out. But you should try figuring out stuff like that on your own using the grad matlab documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into your situation and it seems that the problem *not* trivial as anticipated. Keep in mind that if I have made mistakes on the assumption of the location of the data, you can let me know so I can edit it, or you can just change the numbers to that which suits your case. In this case, I initially loaded the delimited file into an Excel spreadsheet, just to visualize it.

After reading up on [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), I found that one can specify the exact rows and columns to pull from `example.txt`, as shown here:

```
data = dlmread('example.txt', ' ', [4 1 45 37]); % [r1 c1 r2 c2]
data2 = dlmread('example.txt', ' ', [47 1 88 37]);
```

The result of which is two matrices that are `41-by-37`, containing only numbers. I started `data` at row 4 to bypass the header information/strings. Noticing the pattern, I set it up as a loop:

```
No_of_matrices_expected = 4;
dataCell = cell(No_of_matrices_expected, 1);
iterations = length(dataCell)

% Initial Conditions
rowBeginning = 4;
col1 = 1; % Constant
rowEnd = rowBeginning + 40; % == 44, right before next header information
col2 = 36; % Constant

for n = 1 : iterations
    dataCell{n} = dlmread('example.txt', ' ', [rowBeginning, col1, rowEnd, col2]);
    rowBeginning = rowBeginning + 41 + 2; % skip previous matrix and skip header info
    rowEnd = rowBeginning + 40;
end
```

*However*, I stumbled across what you stated earlier which was that there are four different stations, each with their own time stamps. So running this loop more than 4 times led to unexpected results and MATLAB crashed. The reason is that the new timestamp creates an extra row for the date. Now, you could change the loop above to compensate for this extra row, or you can make multiple `for` loops for each station. This will be your decision to make.

Now if you wanted to save the header information, I would recommend taking a look into [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html). You can simply use this function to pull the first column of all the data into a cell array of strings. Then you can pull out the header information that you want. Keep in mind, use [`fopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) if you want to use `textscan`.

I'll let you use what I have found thus far, but let me know if you need more help.

Numbers

Comment: Thanks Numbers682! How about the error: Error using dlmread (line 147)
Mismatch between file and format character vector.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 41, field number 26) ==> date and time\n. The problem with loading in excel, or using interactive export into Malab that the number under FACTOR is separated into several values. For example: 0.016 E-06 is divided into 0.016 and E and -0.6... so it is a problem. Could you offer further help?

Comment: and actually the matrix is 41 rows x 36 column

Comment: Barack, I'm looking into it. I edited the code above by changing some numbers around. I'm wondering why MATLAB is seeing the `date and time` string, even though we can both see in excel that it is in a separate line. I'll follow up if I find anything new.

Comment: As far as Excel, that is beyond my scope. Like I said earlier, I am using it to just visualize what I am working with. In short, you can always merge cells in Excel to combine the data.